# What is the most efficient way to return the first / fastest M results of a set of N asynchronous calls in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm applying a slow asynchronous predicate function (it calls an external HTTP API) to a list of N inputs. I only need any M (where M <= N) inputs for which the function returns true. My first attempt is:

```
var async = require('async');

function asyncFilterFirstM(inputs, m, fn, finalCb) {
  var outs = [];
  var alreadyReturned = false;

  async.map(inputs, function(input, cb) {
    fn(input, function(ret) {
      if (ret) {
        outs.push(input);
        if (outs.length === m) {
          alreadyReturned = true;
          finalCb(null, outs);
        }
      }

      cb(null, ret);      
    });
  }, function(err) {
    if (!alreadyReturned) {
      if (err) return finalCb(err);
      finalCb(null, outs);
    }
  });
}
```

The problem with this version is:

1. The remaining M - N calls are not canceled.
2. `finalCb` is not necessarily called immediately. It tends to block behind the rest of the ongoing slow calls, defeating the purpose of the intended optimization.

Comment: Do you want to immediately launch all N async operations and just cancel the rest when you've found M with the proper result?  Or do you only want to have X async operations in flight at any given time (where X < M < N)?  Is there a way to cancel async operations that are in flight, but are no longer needed?

Comment: I want to launch all N concurrently at the beginning and ideally cancel the rest once I have M true results. But yes, good point, I should have a clearer idea of how this "cancel" actually works or if it's possible.

Comment: (If the cancel actually causes the other functions to return immediately then I should be good to go.)

Comment: You could run in batches of M or whatever remaining numbers required.
Look at [eachLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachlimitarr-limit-iterator-callback)
This may not match your expectations 100%. But, could limit the unwanted calls.

Comment: @palanik Thanks, but I don't think it would work for my exact use-case. I'm optimizing on the overall speed, not the number of calls (or number of concurrent calls). Having it take the maximum time of the concurrently-executed calls is preferable to the worst-case scenario of staggered calls.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your function to return before all operations are done, then I don't think you can use async#map. Also, async does not present any API to cancel a running task.

Here's how I'd do it. Each iterator can return an abort function. It could be as simple as:

```
function (input, done) {
  var req = http.createClient();
  …

  return function () {
    req.abort();
  }
}
```

if you're doing an HTTP request.

```
function asyncMapFastest(arr, m, iterator, done) {
  var remaining = m,
      results = {},
      aborts = [],
      finished = false;

  function abortStillRunning() {
    finished = true;
    aborts.forEach(function (abort) {
      if (abort)
        abort();
    });
    aborts = [];
  }

  arr.forEach(function (input, i) {
    var abort = iterator(input, function (err, result) {
      if (finished)
        return;

      if (err) {
        abortStillRunning();

        return done(err);
      }

      remaining--;
      results[input] = result;
      aborts[i] = null;

      if (remaining === 0) {
        abortStillRunning();

        return done(null, results);
      }
    });

    aborts[i] = abort;
  });
}
```

Comment: also, it will abort everything at the first error, but you can change that easily.